# How to represent weak entity (License) having a composite key of License Number and Driver Number where Driver Number is a foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to represent a one-to-one relationship with a driver and a license where the license is a weak entity having a composite key of the license number and the driver number.
The driver number is a foreign key that refers to the primary key of the user table.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE license (
    driver SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    license_number SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    expiration_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (driver, license_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (driver) REFERENCES user(user_id)
);
```

How can I use the annotation `@EmbeddedKey` and `@Embeddable`?
My understanding is that there should be a new class called LicenseId that implements serializable and has two fields (the license number and the driver id), But I don't know how to tell JPA that this driver Id refers to the primary Id of the user
What I have done so far in terms of classes and entities:

```java
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Embeddable
public class LicenseId implements Serializable {
    private int driver;
    private int licenseNumber;
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
public class License {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LicenseId licenseId;

    @Column(name = "expiration_date", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp expirationDate;

}
```

Comment: should a driver be allowed to holder multiple licenses?

Comment: Do you actually want just driver ID to be the PK or driverID + license

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos No, only one license

Comment: @MasonStedman No I want it to be a composite key of driverID and License Number

Comment: @Ghost0fAlexandria then my answer under is the one you need

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos then surely I have to modify the SQL tables accordingly, correct?

Comment: you either modify the SQL tables by yourself or you let the ORM provider do it for you when you update the entity layer with the annotations I have provided to you and you set the property `spring.jpa.hibernate:.ddl-auto: update`

Comment: @Ghost0fAlexandria please accept the answer if it has helped you solve your problem. You can always upvote as well ;)